# c++ partial specialization match reference type

Tags: c++, templates, reference, partial, specialization

In this code:

```
// decomplexify ---------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
struct decomplexify
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename ELT>
struct decomplexify<std::complex<ELT> >
{
  typedef ELT type;
};
```

It appears the partial specialization will work for

```
decomplexify<std::complex<T>>,
```

but not

```
decomplexify<std::complex<T>&>
```

This is on gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1)

Does this seem expected behavior?  Is there a workaround (other than a redundant specialization for std::complex&?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this behaviour is expected. Here's a possible workaround:

```
template <typename T>
struct decomplexify_impl
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename ELT>
struct decomplexify_impl<std::complex<ELT> >
{
  typedef ELT type;
};

#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct decomplexify
{
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TT;
  typedef typename decomplexify_impl<TT>::type type;
};
```

If you don't intent to use the class with types other than `std::complex` specializations, I suggest you leave the primary template undefined, so that the compiler catches it and errors out.

There's also `value_type` member typedef of `std::complex<T>` that gives you `T` (maybe that's all you need).

Comment: very nice, thanks!  In this case the resulting type would have the reference removed, which I think is what I want.  But just for curiosity, is there a solution that would preserve reference? `decomplexify<std::complex<double>&>::type == double&` ?